# When does an std::string's _M_p become null?

Tags: c++, stl, stdstring

While debugging a crash I noticed that _M_p of a string is null, but other properties seem to still contain remnants of a previous value.

Does anyone know which situation can cause _M_p to be null?
I thought maybe move semantics, but couldn't reproduce this myself.

Comment: I don't think this is specified by the standard, so it would help to know the standard library implementation you used.

Comment: gcc 5.4.0 c++14

Comment: It's an implementation detail, sometimes it doesn't even get a value (small string optimization). So I wouldn't worry about it too much

Comment: @AlonGranot *Does anyone know which situation can cause _M_p to be null?* -- Maybe the `std::string` object is invalid, so looking at internals isn't going to be helpful.

Comment: When a `std::string` is **moved** from, it will be left in an *valid but unspecified state* suitable for being *assigned to* or to be *destructed*.

Comment: @AlonGranot: I suspect the GCC version is less relevant than the libstdc++ version. But as Pepijn notes, SSO means that you'll need to check if `_M_p` is aliased.